# Microsoft R Server Parsing errors

Tags: sql-server, r, stored-procedures, microsoft-r

It is really lame that you can't just copy/paste code from RStudio to a SQL Server stored procedure seamlessly, but alas, it wouldn't be Microsoft otherwise, right?

Basically, I get really strange errors in parsing:

```
Error in source(revoScriptConnection) : 
  revoScriptConnection:116:111: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
116: dtCumulativeResults[,c("State_Name_RAW","City_Name_MDM","County_Name_MDM","State_Name_MDM","City_Address_MDM","City_
```

Here is the actual code line (with a few lines prior included):

```
    }


 }

##save dud results if no geocoding occurred
dtCumulativeResults <- data.table(City_Name_RAW=NA)
dtCumulativeResults[,c("State_Name_RAW","City_Name_MDM","County_Name_MDM","State_Name_MDM","City_Address_MDM","City_Latitude","City_Longitude","index"):=character()]
```

The only lines preceding this are the ending brackets for a for loop and if statement.

This code runs just fine in RStudio.  Unfortunately, if I just isolate these few lines, the SPROC runs.  So it has to do with some lines above, but I couldn't possibly know where to start.  One thing I do know:  it's having problems parsing out braces `{` or `}`.  If I don't indent the braces it throws errors.  But not always.

Anyway, I was hoping someone had realized what the silver bullet is.  Perhaps keep braces on one line.  Etc.  I am adding the full SPROC below, but again, this is some weird formatting issue.

```
USE master
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Rscript_geocodeUSACities]    Script Date: 8/8/2017 10:31:15 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO



























CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Rscript_geocodeUSACities]
    @usrOutputFilePath varchar(150)
    ,@usrOutputFileName varchar(150)

AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @rScript nvarchar(max) = N'

#### USER INPUTS ####

usrOutputFile <- "' + @usrOutputFilePath + @usrOutputFileName + '"


#### ESTABLISH ENVIRONMENT ####

library(data.table)
library(foreach)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)

##turn off scientific notation
options(scipen=999)


#### GEOCODE ####

##assign input data set
dtInputData <- data.table(InputDataSet)

##initialize cumulative results data table
dtCumulativeResults <- dtInputData[0,]

##find out where to start
startindex <- 1

##if a temp file exists - load it up and count the rows
if (file.exists(usrOutputFile)) {

    print("Found temp file - resuming from index")
    dtCumulativeResults <- fread(usrOutputFile,colClasses="character")
    startindex <- ifelse(is.na(max(as.numeric(dtCumulativeResults$index),na.rm=T)),1,max(as.numeric(dtCumulativeResults$index),na.rm=T)+1)
    print(startindex)


} else { print("No temp file") }



if (startindex<nrow(dtInputData) | startindex==nrow(dtInputData)) {

    for (ii in seq(startindex,nrow(dtInputData))) {

    ##initialize temporary results data table
    dtTempResults <- dtInputData[ii,]

    ##geocode address
    vcSearchInput <- paste0(gsub("[[:punct:]]","",unlist(strsplit(paste(dtInputData$City_Name_RAW[ii],dtInputData$State_Name_RAW[ii],"USA")," "))),collapse="+")
    vcSearchURL <- URLencode(paste("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=",vcSearchInput,"&sensor=false",sep=""))
    vcSearchOutput <- getURL(vcSearchURL)
    vcSearchOutput <- fromJSON(vcSearchOutput,simplify=F)

    if (vcSearchOutput$status=="OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {

    dtTempResults[1,c("City_Name_MDM","County_Name_MDM","State_Name_MDM","City_Address_MDM","City_Latitude","City_Longitude","index"):=NA]

    #save temporary results as we are going along
    dtCumulativeResults <- rbind(dtCumulativeResults,dtTempResults[0,],fill=T)
    write.csv(dtCumulativeResults,usrOutputFile,row.names=F)
    break

     }

    if (vcSearchOutput$status=="OK" & !(tolower(dtTempResults$City_Name_RAW) %in% tolower(state.name)) & !(tolower(dtTempResults$City_Name_RAW) %in% tolower(state.abb)) & !(tolower(vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name) %in% tolower(state.name))) {

    dtTempResults[1,City_Name_MDM:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name]

    if (regexpr("County|Parish|Borough",vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]$long_name)>0) {

    dtTempResults[1,County_Name_MDM:=gsub(" County","",vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]$long_name)]
    dtTempResults[1,State_Name_MDM:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$long_name]

    } else if (regexpr("United States",vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$long_name)>0) {

    dtTempResults[1,County_Name_MDM:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[1]]$long_name]
    dtTempResults[1,State_Name_MDM:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[2]]$long_name]


    } else {

    dtTempResults[1,County_Name_MDM:=gsub(" County","",vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[3]]$long_name)]
    dtTempResults[1,State_Name_MDM:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$address_components[[4]]$long_name]

     }

    dtTempResults[1,City_Address_MDM:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$formatted_address]
    dtTempResults[1,City_Latitude:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat]
    dtTempResults[1,City_Longitude:=vcSearchOutput$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng]
    dtTempResults[1,index:=ii]

     }

    ##save temporary results as we are going along
    dtCumulativeResults <- rbind(dtCumulativeResults,dtTempResults,fill=T)
    write.csv(dtCumulativeResults,usrOutputFile,row.names=F)

    }

} else {

    ##save dud results if no geocoding occurred
    dtCumulativeResults <- data.table(City_Name_RAW=NA)
    dtCumulativeResults[,c("State_Name_RAW","City_Name_MDM","County_Name_MDM","State_Name_MDM","City_Address_MDM","City_Latitude","City_Longitude","index"):=character()]
    write.csv(dtCumulativeResults[0,],usrOutputFile,row.names=F)

    }

'

EXECUTE  sp_execute_external_script
                @language = N'R'
              , @script = @rScript
              ,@input_data_1 =N'select distinct [City_Name_RAW]
                                    ,[State_Name_RAW]
                                from [External].[mdm].[dim_USA_Cities_Map]
                                where Mod_DT is null'
              ;

END


























GO
```

Comment: Then there's a good chance the problem is in the lines before those two, which we can't see.

Comment: I added the few lines prior (which are just closing brackets).  Also the error claims the string isn't terminated, but the actual code shows that it is.

Comment: For example, if I collapse the ending brackets right before these lines onto the same line, now the unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING error comes a few character spaces later on the same line

Comment: If you claim that the problem might be in the procedure above those two lines, anything but the full procedure text in your question is likely to get your question closed.

Comment: OK I added the full code, but I don't think it will really help.  You'll have to go line-by-line (which I can do) to find the source of the problem, but the question remains:  why can't you just copy/paste code in?

Comment: Also you won't have the input data set created by the SQL query...In this case it is actually blank, so if you just want to create a dud table, the script needs to work when there are no input rows anyway.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you save to a csv file? You're in a database, you can just write the results back to a table.

Comment: I might just switch to this.  I have not used any RevoScale functions yet.  What should I use to insert 1 row at a time?

Comment: It seems like you can't insert a single row from a for loop in R into a SQL Server table.  This is why I write to .csv.  In case the loop breaks, I can restart without losing my progress.

Comment: Note that the bulk of your script is specified as a non-Unicode string literal.  Everyting after `usrOutputFile <- "' + @usrOutputFilePath + @usrOutputFileName + '"`  Because after the '+' you start the next string literal without N'

Comment: @David Browne can you make this the official answer!  This was the problem!  Also, could you maybe quickly tell me how I can convert this to append the loop results row-by-row to a SQL table?  I tried using rxDataStep function with outFile = imp.USA_Cities_Map (table name) but it says "cannot find file"

Comment: @PabloBoswell Different question, perhaps worthy of a new question?

Comment: @TT. added the question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574968/microsoft-r-server-row-by-row-insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the bulk of your script is specified as a non-Unicode string literal. Everyting after

```
usrOutputFile <- "' + @usrOutputFilePath + @usrOutputFileName + '"  . . .
```

Because after the '+' you start the next string literal without N' .  Should be

```
usrOutputFile <- "' + @usrOutputFilePath + @usrOutputFileName + N'"  . . .
```

To insert the results to a table, in TSQL use INSERT ... EXEC .  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql

Comment: The issue with INSERT...EXEC is that EXEC is a loop and I want to write each iteration to a SQL table as I go

Comment: Added the question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574968/microsoft-r-server-row-by-row-insert